# How to get a conditional inline styling in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a condition inline style but it returns this error

```
Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string
```

this is the code:

```
<div className="todo" style={todo.isCompleted ? {textDecoration: 'line-through'} : '' }>{todo.text}</div>
```

I checked online but found nothing that could help me solve this.
Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of using it.

```
<div className="todo" style={{text-decoration: todo.isCompleted ? 'line-through' : 'none' }}>{todo.text}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you want to render the style conditionally you can use the conditional spread operator like this:

```
<div 
   className="todo"
   {...(todo.isCompleted && {style: {textDecoration: 'line-through'}})}
>
  {todo.text}
</div>
```

In that way you are going to render the style prop, only if the condition is fulfilled.

The reason why it is complaining is that the second condition in your ternary operator is an empty string and react expects a valid style object.